# Make a new column from grouped data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas Dataframe as below-

```py
id  session_id  timestamp   url
1      #123        1       a.com
1      #123        2       a.com
1      #123        3       b.com
1      #123        4       b.com
1      #123        5       a.com
1      #546        37      c.com
2      #342        78      b.com
2      #674        79      c.com
```

I want to group all data using `id` then `session_id` and calculate the total timespent on each url.

code to make DataFrame -

```py
pd.DataFrame({
    'id':[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
    'session_id':['#123', '#123', '#123', '#123', '#123', '#546', '#342', '#674'],
    'url':['a.com', 'a.com', 'b.com', 'b.com', 'a.com', 'c.com', 'b.com', 'c.com'],
    'timestamp':[1,2,3,4,5,37,78,79]
})
```

> Timespent is calculated as `2(timestamp)-1(timestamp)=1` (actual data has timestamp as UNIX timestamp), now for id
>   `1` and session_id `#123` - `a.com` has total_timespent as (2-1)+(5-4) =
>   2 (because 3,4 timestamp is for `b.com`)

**Expected Output -**

```py
id  session_id  timestamp   url    total_time
1      #123        1       a.com       2
1      #123        2       a.com       2
1      #123        3       b.com       2
1      #123        4       b.com       2
1      #123        5       a.com       2
1      #546        37      c.com       0
2      #342        78      b.com       0
2      #674        79      c.com       0
```

here time for a url is broadcasted to all rows for a url  (as per id and session_id)

Comment: Why the total_time for c.com is 0?

Comment: Because there is no other timestamp to compare with in session #546 or in #674.

Comment: Shouldn't the time spent of b.com = 2? (3-2) + (4 - 3)?

Comment: think of it as - you visited a url `b.com` and time is noted as `3` and then you bounced from that url with last time noted as `4` - I want to keep this time as 1 (4-3)

Comment: yes @DanielMesejo, sorry for that I didn't thought about it earlier and it should be applied same, editing the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first calculate the time difference of each entry per session and store this in a new column time_diff:

```
df['time_diff'] = df.groupby(['id', 'session_id']).diff().fillna(0)
```

And then for each url in a session you can sum the time spend on that url:

```
df['total_time'] = df.groupby(['id', 'session_id', 'url'])['time_diff'].transform('sum')
```

Which leads to this output:

```
id  session_id  url timestamp   time_diff   total
0   1   #123    a.com   1   0.0 2.0
1   1   #123    a.com   2   1.0 2.0
2   1   #123    b.com   3   0.0 2.0
3   1   #123    b.com   4   1.0 2.0
4   1   #123    a.com   5   1.0 2.0
5   1   #546    c.com   37  0.0 0.0
6   2   #342    b.com   78  0.0 0.0
7   2   #674    c.com   79  0.0 0.0
```

Comment: No, i think this is the right answer with the description laid out by OP. i think the OP needs to actually lay out how to calculate the times correctly again, since if they state (5-4) as part of time for "a.com", then (3-2) should also be time at "b.com".

Comment: If correct then use `df['time_diff'] = df.groupby(['id', 'session_id']).diff()

df['time_diff'] = df.groupby(['id', 'session_id', 'url'])['time_diff'].transform('sum')`

Comment: yes, @ParitoshSingh (3-2) is the time at "b.com" that's why in expected output `b.com` has time as `1`

Comment: @Himanshu except 4-3 is *also* time spent at "b.com" no? (just as you added 2-1 for a)

Comment: ok, I am accepting the answer and editing the expected output, as i didn't thought about the switch time from `a.com` to `b.com` earlier but  this answer is right.

Comment: Just saw your comment. I will revert my changes